# Horizontal scroll container full-width BUT with left margin align to non full-width containers

Tags: css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I wanted to share my experience with styling a horizontal carousel in WordPress, similar to those seen in Netflix thematic containers. I'm not sure if I did it correctly or if there are better options.

Here is the result I am looking for:

[image]

I have a full-width container with a query loop and specific CSS styles:

```
.hscroll {
    flex-wrap: nowrap!important;
    overflow-x: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: calc((100% - 610px) / 2); /* 610px is the width of non full-width content */
}
```

I also hid the scrollbar. Is that a good idea?

```
.no-scrollbar {
  scrollbar-width: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```